# How to curl endpoint on Docker Container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, virtualization

I have this stack named `ms_billing` that is deployed on a swarm cluster using `docker stack deploy`.

[image]

I want to `curl` an endpoint on this service `ms_billing_api` which is running on my host called `dev-ms-slave1`

[image]

which has this IP: `192.168.99.101`

[image]

So I opened a new bash and tried `curl 192.168.99.101:8080/billing/api/v1/health-check`, which is my endpoint, but I got `(7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.101 port 8080: Connection refused`

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you curl it from within the VM?

Comment: I dont think so :(

Comment: `curl localhost:8080/billing/api/v1/health-check` also dont respond

Comment: If they're part of a swarm you should be able to curl any of the machines on port 8080 to get the result. Are you sure it is running? If you're using Docker 17.06CE you can run `docker service logs` to get logs for the task. Also did the service use port 8080 internally? Is it exposed in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Ok, Thank for your help, the actual problem was on the service itself and not in the infrastructure.

Comment: Ye, if you couldn't curl from inside either that's pretty much the only place it could be :)